# How expose a exported function into global scope with babel and webpack

Tags: webpack, babeljs

How can I compile my code with webpack and babel so that the exported function is available in the global scope.

So for example:

```
export function test(){console.log('test')}
```

Should be available under `window.test()`.

When I just run `babel -d` I got what I expect:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
  value: true
});
exports.test = test;

function test() {
  console.log('test');
}
```

but the webpack output looks like this:

```
!function(e) {
  function t(r) {
    if (o[r])return o[r].exports;
    var n = o[r] = {exports: {}, id: r, loaded: !1};
    return e[r].call(n.exports, n, n.exports, t), n.loaded = !0, n.exports
  }

  var o = {};
  return t.m = e, t.c = o, t.p = "", t(0)
}([function(e, t) {
  "use strict";
  function o() {
    console.log("test")
  }

  Object.defineProperty(t, "__esModule", {value: !0}), t.test = o
}]);
```

end the `test` function is not available in the global scope.

Comment: Any update on this? I've been trying to learn to do the same for a while now.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, only dynamically create window/globals. Expose-loader works, but breaks down when you need to expose a TON of globals

Comment: @user1828780 There's a plugin for that
https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-global-scope

Answer (score 10, accepted):

check out:
https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/library-and-externals#examples

By setting the **library** output property to whatever name you want to wrap your globals would allow you to then call: **YourLibrary**.test();

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./_js/script.js'],
    output: {
       library: 'YourLibrary',
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './build/script.js'
    }
```

Comment: but how to just export one function

Comment: in the example above do you mean just calling `YourLibrary()` as a function, i'm not sure if that is possible. You can however only expose/export a single function, for example, export function `foo(){...`  then call `YourLibrary.foo()`

Comment: yes, but I need call functions in other module exported in `YourLibrary.foo()`

Answer (score 13):

You can easily set a property on the global `window` object. This will expose your object to the global scope.

```
function test() {
  console.log('test');
}

window.test = test;
```

If you are developing a piece of code that does not represent a library but just some operations or functionalities to operate in global scope, I would prefer this method over to setting the library output property as mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `window.test` is undefined

Comment: try using window['test'] = test and make sure you call it after the js is loaded.

Comment: very bad practice