# function exported into global scope is undefined (webpack + babel)

Tags: javascript, webpack, global, babeljs

I have three separate libraries -

1. Lib A - Hosts shared code and uses babel to transpile the code into a /lib folder
2. Lib B - which uses libA (imports the babel transpiled code) and it uses webpack to generate the bundle in a dist folder (dist/index.js). It also exports a global function "myGlobalFunction" by attaching it to a window.
3. Lib C - Uses both A and the global "myGlobalFunction".

**Issue is, the window.myGlobalFunction when accessed from lib C, prints undefined.**

In Library B, if I import the contents of Lib A from src/ instead of the transpiled lib/, my issue gets resolved automatically.

Not sure why this is happening.
Also, I have disabled the es modules transpilation in babel by setting

```
{modules: false}
```

in babelrc of the libA.

I have a problem [similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33148787/how-expose-a-exported-function-into-global-scope-with-babel-and-webpack) but the solution posted there didnt work either as I need to use the global in some another library by directly looking in the Window object.

All the libraries are separate npm packages.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue being how babel was transpiling the code from LibA  - especially the code including async...await.

It uses the preset env and fb's regenerator runtime to transpile async..await into Promises using generators.

I disabled the "transform-regenerator", "transform-async-to-generator" plugins and used [fast-async plugin](https://air.ghost.io/transforming-async-await-js-and-minifying-using-uglify/) to do the job and my issue was resolved.

Another way is to use the babel's [transform runtime plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#regenerator-aliasing) which also solved my issue.

I suspect the main issue was the code which uses regeneratorRuntime was not being resolved, not sure about that, but the workaround solved my problem.