# Exported function is undefined in bundle.js after webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have have build process that is managed by Webpack. It bundles all my files up and generates a single `bundle.js` file. Very typical pattern.

However, when I include that file `bundle.js` in a webpage, **the exported default function is undefined.** Why can't I access that exported function from the global scope on a webpage?

Here is my webpack config:

```js
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'assets'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `bundle.css`,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Here is a simplified `src/js/index.js`:

```js
import util from './util';
import as dependency from 'external-library';
import EventEmitter from 'events';

/**
 * MyLibrary module
 * @module MyLibrary
 * @class
 * @param {MyLibraryOptions} options - Options to initialize the module with
 * @returns {Object} MyLibrary instance
 */
export default function MyLibrary(options) {
    if (!(this instanceof MyLibrary)) {
        return new MyLibrary(options);
    }
    
    //...Do a bunch of stuff.

}
```

**The goal is to include `bundle.js` on a webpage and access in a script tag such as:**

```js
var instance = new MyLibrary({option_1: value, ...})
```

However, when I do this `MyLibrary` is always undefined.

UPDATE:

After adding the `library` property as in the webpack config, `MyLibrary` is not undefined, but I can't call it. It's a module now.

[image]

UPDATE 2 --> SOLUTION:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        library: 'MyLibrary',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        libraryExport: 'default',
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
   }
...
```

Comment: Is the last bit of code running the browser?

Comment: @CalderWhite Yes, I get an error that MyLibrary is undefined.

Comment: How did you include the js in the webpage? <script src=".."> or some other way?

Comment: @h00ligan That's correct. I just included my JS file with a `script`(in my case, `bundle.js`) tag before my library instantiates.

Answer (score 5):

In webpack the default scope is not global. It contains all your code in an anonymous function. To expose your library to the global scope of the browser, [use this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33981221/5709499).

Your webpack config would look like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/js/index.js',
    output: {
        library: 'MyLibrary',
        path: path.resolve('dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules', path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'assets'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'file-loader',
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `bundle.css`,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: This is really close...but now `MyLibrary` is just a module. I can't call `new MyLibrary()`. Checkout my update question.

Comment: @calbear47 are you saying that you have to call something like `MyLibrary.MyLibrary`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. I would like to just call MyLibrary()

Comment: I believe libraryTarget is related to what you're after. Try my edit, and if that doesn't work we can go further from this documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrarytarget.

Comment: @calbear47 ^^^^

Comment: libraryTarget looks promising for sure. However, when I try the 'assign' option I'm still  getting a module back as before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196430/discussion-between-calder-white-and-calbear47).